# Does jasmine need sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

I've seen examples on the web in which people use [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) together with [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). However, jasmine has support for spies (which as I understand is what Sinon does). So, the question is, is Sinon still useful when using Jasmine ? If Sinon is useful what exactly makes it a good addition to jasmine ?

Cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No you dont need Sinon to work with Jasmine. But Sinon spy/mock/stubs are more convenient in some cases. There is also a minor bug in mocking setTimeout in Jasmine, which work as expected with sinon.

Comment: do we need to do a require('sinon') to access this on our test page?

Comment: When using sinon's spies and mocks instead of Jasmine's bear in mind that you won't get Jasmine's informative stack traces that come with a failed `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value)` which tell you what the spy was _actually_ called with. With sinon the expectation just silently fails `expected false to be true`

Answer (score 11):

I use Sinon with Jasmine for it's [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer) capabilities. Sinon allows me to easily mock AJAX HTTP requests without relying on the state of my server. Sinon also provides lower-level http mocking functionality for when you really need to fine-tune your mocked services.

Answer (score 7):

You can use SinonJS as an extension to Jasmine. Sinon has a very nice API for a mock server which is quite handy if you want to test REST calls without having a real backend. There is also a nice documentation which shows the combination of [SinonJS with Jasmine](http://rest-samples.ahus1.de/test/rec_jasmine_sinon.html).

Comment: To be expected, but the link in this answer is now dead.