# setting up jasmine with sinon

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

In my package.json I installed sinon.  With mocha and chai I would use a

```
 var sinon = require('sinon');
```

Would this also be the case for testing with jasmine?   Although jasmine comes with their own spies I would like to play with stubs and spies with sinon for some of my unit tests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do most things with Jasmine that you can with Sinon. Installing Sinon seems redundant. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15002541/230167

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did see that before and noticed the answer.  Which was what drew me to trying it out.